# Correct terminology for types of git ref

Tags: git

The git docs mention `commitish`, `ref` and `refspec`.

I write scripts. I want my terminology to be correct, so other people learn git as they use the scripts.

In my repo `foo`, I have a remote `origin` that points to my upstream `https://github/fsackur/foo`. My branch `bar` is checked out at SHA `deadbeef` and tracks `origin/bar`.

1. What is the correct name for a parameter that accepts any of `bar`, `origin/bar`, `deadbeef`, or the literal string `HEAD`?
2. What is the correct name for a parameter that accepts `foo:bar` or `fsckur:bar`? Please clarify if this is github functionality rather than git.
3. If not yet clear from 1 and 2, what is the difference in git terminology between `commitish`, `ref` and `refspec`?

Comment: 1 is `committish`, to the best of my knowledge. Check https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Definitions from the glossary*
[commit-ish](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish)
[ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefrefaref)
[refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefrefspecarefspec)

---

*Answering your sub-questions*

> 1. *A parameter that accepts any of bar, `origin/bar`, `deadbeef`, or the literal string `HEAD`*

...as [eftshift0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2437508/eftshift0) already mentioned in his comment on the question, would be a `<commitish>`, meaning anything that can be ultimately dereferenced down to a commit hash. So it could as well be a branch, a commit hash, a tag, many things. As [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) commented below, most of the time simple refs are used for `<commitish>`.

> 2. *the correct name for a parameter that accepts `foo:bar` or `fsckur:bar`*

...is a `<refspec>`, as described in [git push man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203) for example, but you have it also for `fetch` or `pull`.

> 3. *what is the difference in git terminology between commitish, ref and refspec?*

The third one from your list we didn't mention yet is the simple `ref`, which basically means "variable" in git. The `.git/refs` folder of a git repo is storing variables along with their value, which is a hash.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that many frequently used commit-ish values are simply refs. The only non-ref example given by OP is the commit hash.

Comment: @JoachimSauer You're right. I've edited.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that GItHub sometimes use `br1:br2` syntax (which Git would accept as a refspec in a command that takes refspecs) for their own purposes when generating output. Here, it's not a Git thing at all, just a GitHub thing.